# how to put array into <textarea>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm obtaining the list from ip-adresses from mysql database
the common output is something like that:

```
217.11.25.15217.11.25.16217.11.25.17
```

so each ip-adress is a value from the mysql table

and when i'm trying to show a table each ip-adress takes one td tag, so in order to display 3 adresses i need to print 3 table rows:

```
sample data sample data 217.11.65.1
sample data sample data 217.11.65.2
sample data sample data 217.11.65.3
```

how to put an array into one textarea to make an output look like the following:

```
                        217.11.65.1
sample data sample data 217.11.65.2
                        217.11.65.3
```

firstly i tried something like that:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ip from ip1 where id<5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $ip = $row['ip'].'<br />';
    echo "<textarea rows='7'>".$ip."</textarea>";
}
```

But it didn't end up successfully

i used

```
$content = "<textarea rows='7'>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ip from ip1 where id<5");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $ip = $row['ip'].' \n ';
    $content .= $ip;
}

$content .= "</textarea>";

echo $content;
```

And the output is:

```
217.11.65.0 \n 
217.11.65.1 \n 
217.11.65.2 \n 
217.11.65.3 \n
```

How to get rid of this \n?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: How do you know where does a ip end and the other begin?

Comment: Are they all the same? In that case it doesnt make sense. I dont find this useful. What are you doing?

Comment: they are not the same: 217.11.65.1, 217.11.65.2, 217.11.65.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $ip = '';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ip from ip1 where id<5");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $ip .= $row['ip'].'<br />';
    }

    $ip = str_ireplace('<br />', "\r\n", $ip);
    echo "<textarea rows='7'>".$ip."</textarea>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is dont work, because you create multiple `<textarea>`, try this:

```
$content = "<textarea rows='7'>";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT ip from ip1 where id<5");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $ip = $row['ip'].'<br />';
        $content .= $ip;
    }

$content .= "</textarea>";

echo $content;
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cotenteditable` div, if you will have result like

```
                        217.11.65.1
sample data sample data 217.11.65.2
                        217.11.65.3
```

If you will have result like

```
217.11.65.1
217.11.65.2
217.11.65.3
```

implode `ip`'s with `\n`:

```
$ips = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $ips[] = $row['ip'];
}
echo "<textarea rows='7'>".implode('\n', $ips)."</textarea>";
```